# PHP: Can't access to website when script is processing

Tags: php

When I access `http://localhost/myapp111/index/` then this script will excute:

```
$a = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < 100000000; ++$i) {
    $a = $a +$i ;
}
```

then I can't  access `http://localhost/myapp111/*` ( can't access any page on myapp111, i must wait above script complete)

but I can access `http://localhost/myapp2222/*`

What is the reason for this ? Is there any way to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be PHP sessions, I can't remember if they serialize requests participating in the same session.

Comment: thanks a lot, it is session. I use cakephp framework, if i config save sessions in database, then this matter don't happen ( even i don't know exactly why :D ) .

Comment: If file sessions didn't lock out other requests from the same session, then you could have race conditions where two pages try to update the same session and stomp on each other's changes. I guess the database sessions use locks at the variable level instead of the session level, so you don't notice it as often.

Comment: If i dont config it will use PHP default's session handling method then this matter will happen.